# Why does the next line get printed when I call readline() multiple times instead of printing the first line

Tags: python, input, output

Please explain how the readline()  method is different from the readlines()

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? it clearly explains the difference between `readline` and `readlines`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response

Comment: Hey I read the entire documentation and I understand the difference between readline and realines , I jus twang to know why it moves to the next line . I also saw couple while loop examples but they didn’t help much :(

Comment: Btw I am a complete beginner in Python soooo........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readline method reads one line from the file and returns it as a string. The string returned by readline will contain the newline character at the end. The readlines method returns the contents of the entire file as a list of strings, where each item in the list represents one line of the file.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response

Comment: But what do u mean by reads the line one by one and returns it as a a string.I read the documentation too ,but I still don’t get it . could u please explain it with a an example.I would really appreciate that

Comment: Btw I am a complete beginner soooo.........